# Settting PTBTokenizer's normalizeSpace to false with pycorenlp

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, tokenize

I use [pycorenlp](https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp) to tokenize a text. By [default](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/process/PTBTokenizer.html), any space in tokens (e.g., phone numbers, fractions) gets turned into U+00A0 ([non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)), coded as [`\xC2\xA0` in UTF-8](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm). I [read](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/process/PTBTokenizer.html) that I should set `normalizeSpace` to `False`. How can I do that with pycorenlp?

Here is the code I use:

```
'''
From https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp/blob/master/example.py
'''

from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
import pprint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')
    text = 'I ate 1 1/2 lobster'
    output = nlp.annotate(text, properties={
        'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit',
        'outputFormat': 'json',
        'timeout': '50000',
        'PTBTokenizer.normalizeSpace': 'false'
        #'normalizeSpace': 'false'
    })
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    pp.pprint(output)
    print("output['sentences'][0]['tokens'][2]: {0}".
          format(output['sentences'][0]['tokens'][2]))
```

The output contains `u'word': u'1\xa01/2'`, which shows that spaces are replaced by non-breaking spaces, which I do not want.

The Stanford Core NLP Server was launched using:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer 9000
```

I unsuccessfully tried adding the following in the `properties` dictionary that is passed as a parameter to `nlp.annotate()`:

- `'tokenizer.normalizeSpace': 'false'`
- `'tokenize.normalizeSpace': 'false'`
- `'normalizeSpace': 'false'`
- `'PTBTokenizer.normalizeSpace': 'false'`

Comment: Since the question received no answer, I crossposted it on Quora: https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-can-I-set-PTBTokenizers-normalizeSpace-to-false-with-pycorenlp

Answer (score 0):

below is the way to use it:

*'tokenize.options': 'normalizeSpace=False'*